# How to click on a button with in a submenu with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a webpage, and within it there is a menu that looks like this:

```
<span localization="" data-key="EXPORT_AND_IMPORT" class="ng-binding ng-isolate-scope">Export &amp; Import</span>
```

when I click it, it opens a sub menu with three options:

```
<div class="qmenu dropdown-menu positioned" style="top: 293px; left: 900px; max-height: 99%; width: 231px; height: 113px;"><ul class="menu-items"><li class="no-check"><a><i class="icon icon-download-lg"></i>Export Data...</a></li><li class="no-check"><a><i class="icon icon-uploadcsv-lg"></i>Import Data...</a></li><li class="divider"></li><li class="no-check"><a><i class="icon icon-twofiles"></i>Manage Previous Downloads...</a></li></ul></div>
```

here is a picture:

[image]

How can I press the **Export & Import** button and then the **Export Data** button with in the submenu?

Answer (score 0):

First to `click()` on the element with text as **Export & Import** and then to `click()` on the submenu element with text as **Export Data...** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.ng-binding.ng-isolate-scope[data-key='EXPORT_AND_IMPORT']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.qmenu.dropdown-menu>ul.menu-items li:nth-of-type(1)>a"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ng-binding ng-isolate-scope' and @data-key='EXPORT_AND_IMPORT']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='qmenu dropdown-menu positioned']/ul[@class='menu-items']//li/a[contains(., 'Export Data')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```